# Frame is not available in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging

I am writing a program in Android Studio for my project. However, when I want to debug it, it keeps giving the "frame is not available" error. Does anyone have any idea how to solve it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you click run or debug. Two different buttons.

Comment: Did you pause the program or set breakpoints?

Comment: I'm assuming they got hit. Right?

Comment: I do not understand ur question. It sometimes passes some breakpoints ok and then gives the error. Sometimes , at the beggining gives the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115139/discussion-between-motkohn-and-user2873565).

Comment: I removed some of the checkpoints at the beginning of the code, it seems ok for now, I have other problems that I am trying to solve now. If I struggle again, I will come back to u. Thansk a lot for helping